# Indenting Python function within string and executing it using eval

Tags: python, string, parsing, switch-statement, eval

I've written simple code to handle just one case and correct the indentation (again simple and it relies on the user taking caution while using it) of a string containing a Python function declared using the `def` keyword and execute it.

```py
def fix_index(string):
    i=0;
    t=string.find("def")+3;
    string=string.replace(string[string.find("def"):t], "@") 
    while string.find(" ") != -1:
        string = string.replace(" ", "")
        i += 1
    l=list(string);l[string.find(":")-i+2]+="$$$$" 
    return "".join(l).replace("$$$$", "    ").replace("@", "def ").lstrip();



def switch(exp):
    def exec(obj):
        items = obj.items();
        for k, v in items:
            if(k==exp): 
                print(fix_index(v))
                return eval(fix_index(v))();

    return {"case":exec};
        

bread = "bread"
switch(bread)["case"]({
    "cheese":
    """
def a():
    print("cheese");
    """,
    "bread": 
    """
def b(): 
         print("bread");
    """
})
```

the output for the formatted function string:

```
C:\Users\User>python -u "c:\Users\User\folder\switch.py"
def b():
    print("bread");
```

the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\folder\switch.py", line 27, in <module>
    switch(bread)["case"]({
  File "c:\Users\User\folder\switch.py", line 21, in exec
    return eval(fix_index(v))();
  File "<string>", line 1
    def b():
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've also just realized I didn't name the function what I <s>*indented*</s> intended to (should've posted this when awake to avoid accidental pun).

Anyways what I fail to understand is what part in my produced string exactly contains "invalid syntax".

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: `def` is a statement, `eval` only works on expressions. You want `exec`

Comment: But, uh, whatever it is you are trying to do here it doesn't look like you should be using either

Comment: Agreed. I think you'd be better off with lambdas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if what you are looking for is to reproduce a switch statement, you can do it with the following function:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c: v in c
```

It simulates a switch statement using a single pass for loop with if/elif/else conditions that don't repeat the switching value:

for example:

```
for case in switch(x):
    if    case(3):     
          # ... do something
    elif  case(4,5,6): 
          # ... do something else
    else:              
          # ... do some other thing
```

It can also be used in a more C style:

```
for case in switch(x):

    if case(3):     
       # ... do something
       break

    if case(4,5,6): 
       # ... do something else
       break 
else:              
    # ... do some other thing
```

For your example, it could look like this:

```
meal = "bread"

for case in switch(meal):

    if   case("cheese"):

         print("Cheese!")

    elif case("bread"):

         print("Bread!")
```

or this:

```
meal = "bread"

for case in switch(meal):

    if case("cheese"):
        print("Cheese!")
        break

    if case("bread"):
        print("Bread!")
        break
```